# Adding Multiple footers rows to Gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to add more rows to the footer, but I keep getting a error with my code. I have working on this for a couple of days. Please help!

```
Partial Class Capacity_Plan_Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Property EngTotalQuoteHours As Decimal
    Private Property EngTotalUsedHours As Decimal
    Private Property column1 As Decimal
    Private Property column2 As Decimal
    Private Property column3 As Decimal
    Private Property CNC_5Axis As Decimal
    Private Property CNC_Large As Decimal
    Private Property CNC_Small As Decimal
    Private Property EDM_Large As Decimal
    Private Property EDM_Small As Decimal
    Private Property EDM_Trodes As Decimal
    Private Property Assy As Decimal
    Private Property Polish As Decimal
    Private Property Sample As Decimal

    Private Property orginalDatatable As Data.DataTable

    Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound


        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            Dim hourRow As GridViewRow = e.Row

            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Eng_Quoted_Hrs")) Then
                EngTotalQuoteHours += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Eng_Quoted_Hrs"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Eng_Used_Hrs")) Then
                EngTotalUsedHours += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Eng_Used_Hrs"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "column1")) Then
                column1 += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "column1"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "column2")) Then
                column2 += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "column2"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "column3")) Then
                column3 += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "column3"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CNC_5Axis")) Then
                CNC_5Axis += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CNC_5Axis"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CNC_Large")) Then
                CNC_Large += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CNC_Large"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CNC_Small")) Then
                CNC_Small += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "CNC_Small"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EDM_Large")) Then
                EDM_Large += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EDM_Large"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EDM_Small")) Then
                EDM_Small += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EDM_Small"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EDM_Trodes")) Then
                EDM_Trodes += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "EDM_Trodes"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Assy")) Then
                Assy += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Assy"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Polish")) Then
                Polish += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Polish"))
            End If
            If Not IsDBNull(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Sample")) Then
                Sample += Convert.ToDecimal(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Sample"))
            End If

        ElseIf e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.Footer Then
            e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "Total Hours:"
            e.Row.Cells(5).Text = EngTotalQuoteHours.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(6).Text = EngTotalUsedHours.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(7).Text = column1.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(8).Text = column2.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(9).Text = column3.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(10).Text = CNC_5Axis.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(11).Text = CNC_Large.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(12).Text = CNC_Small.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = EDM_Large.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(14).Text = EDM_Small.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(15).Text = EDM_Trodes.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(16).Text = Assy.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(17).Text = Polish.ToString
            e.Row.Cells(18).Text = Sample.ToString

            Dim GridView1 As GridView = CType(sender, GridView)
            ''gets the current footer row to clone
            Dim footer As GridViewRow = GridView1.FooterRow
            Dim numCells = footer.Cells.Count

            Dim newRow As New GridViewRow(footer.RowIndex + 1, -1, footer.RowType, footer.RowState)

            ''have to add in the right number of cells
            ''this also copies any styles over from the original footer
            For i As Integer = 0 To numCells - 1
                Dim emptyCell As New TableCell
                emptyCell.ApplyStyle(GridView1.Columns(i).ItemStyle)

                newRow.Cells.Add(emptyCell)
            Next

            newRow.Cells(5).Text = (EngTotalQuoteHours / 46).ToString

            ''add new row to the gridview table, at the very bottom
            CType(GridView1.Controls(0), Table).Rows.Add(newRow)

        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

The error that I get is below.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

Line 90:             ''gets the current footer row to clone
Line 91:             Dim footer As GridViewRow = GridView1.FooterRow
Line 92:             Dim numCells = footer.Cells.Count
Line 93: 
Line 94:             Dim newRow As New GridViewRow(footer.RowIndex + 1, -1, footer.RowType, footer.RowState)

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should really post that in your question.  Pretty important part of this.

Comment: Just added the error message that I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case GridView1.FooterRow is null so instead of

```
Dim footer As GridViewRow = GridView1.FooterRow
```

use

```
Dim footer As GridViewRow = e.Row
```